# How the app_code are published in asp.net 2.0 website? Assembly or directly in their classes .cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

In ASP.NET webforms 2.0. Where are the assembly of app_code folder? I have a websited published in production, but haven't the app_code.dll in bin foder, the classes of app_code are all in app_code folder. Its is possible? My website execute those .cs files into app_code folder directly without assembly?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're publishing the web site using a web deployment project, all of the .cs files are going to be compiled into one DLL (or rather, they're all compiled per-folder, and then later joined into one assembly). Also, you can keep the .cs files in App_Code, they will work just as expected (if they weren't compiled with a deployment project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about *website* projects. The JIT compilation kicks in and produces the assembly at this location (depending on version):

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

However, if you are talking about *web application projects* or WAPs, then the precompiled assembly with the name of the project resides in the bin folder. There is *NO* "app_code" magic folder.

That said, in website projects, you can change the temp folder to another folder of your choice by specifying the `tempDirectory` attribute in the `compilation` section of your `web.config`.